# Memory issue when handling huge dataframe and transpose it in Python 2.7

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has about  400k - 700k rows and ~700 columns. The dataframe needs to be transposed meaning only 10 columns fixed the rest need to change from column to rows. I am not asking for transposition logic here. I know how to do that but I am running into a memory error when the transposition operation is performed. I tried to perform the operation in batches but that is taking a lot of time. I wanted to use ProcessPoolExecuter.

```
#df - original df
list_df = [df.iloc[i:i+CHUNK_SIZE] for i in range(0, len(df), CHUNK_SIZE) ]
del df # just to free some memory 
gc.collect()
param_list = [(dummy_df, a, b, c) for dummy_df in list_df] #list of parameters to function
del list_df
gc.collect()
with ProcessPoolExecuter() as executer:
    results = executer.map(function_to_transpose_df, patam_list)
final_df = pd.concat(results )
del results
gc.collect()

#...
```

`param_list` is the list of parameters to the function. I could have used   `*(dummy_df, a, b, c)` for Python 3.5  but how can I unpack in Python 2.7 ? 
`executer.map(function_to_transpose_df, patam_list)` is not going to work in the  current form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hsplit to split data into chunks and then perform transponse and then append the data back ...

Comment: Can you please support this with an example? Currently, its very high-level.